# My azure Virtual machine is in failed status

Tags: azure, azure-storage

My Azure virtual machine is in failed status and its not allowing me to do stop and start. I am getting error message

" Provisioning failed. Could not resolve storage account testrgdiag502. Please ensure it was created through the Storage Resource Provider in the same location as the compute resource.. StorageAccountLocationMismatch "

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the error code, we should check the location of your storage account. This error occurs when the location of the VM disk and the computing resource is **different**.

More information about this error code, please refer to this [link](https://gist.github.com/takekazuomi/0151d8b97e1d096b9e0bc2e25363f6e8).

To resolve this issue, we can **re-create** a new storage account and the location same as Azure VM.

Another way, we can **create a new VM** with this VM's VHD.
Here is a template, we can use this [template](https://github.com/Azure/azure-quickstart-templates/tree/master/201-vm-specialized-vhd) to create a new VM with an existing VHD.

=================================
**Update**:
If your subscription can't create any Azure VM, please new a support request(free), please follow this screenshot:
[image]

Comment: Does it work now? Please let me know if you would like further assistance.

Comment: If it helps, please mark it as an answer so that other community members will be benefited.

Comment: I am sorry not to update you , This VM is a Production running machine and now we are not able to do any operation on this machine because we are getting above error message. In our subscription there is no storage account by name " testrgdiag50 " . Storage account for this machine is completely different. Now when I am trying to create a New VM with different storage account I am still receiving same error message. Overall I am not able to do any operation on this subscription because of same error message.On provisioned VM only storage and Nework part getting created there is no compute.

Comment: @Sham Do you mean you can't create a new VM?

Comment: @Sham If your subscription can't create any Azure VM, please new a support request, I have update my answer, please check it.

Comment: I have checked the update and raised a ticket with support team.